# NSPredicate and NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

Is there a way to setup a `NSPredicate` that will search for all items in an `NSArray`?

something like:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"group.name == %@", arrayOfNames];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "IN" instead of "==" if the right-hand side is an array or set:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"group.name IN %@", arrayOfNames]
```

Comment: Ha! I knew there was a way, but couldn't remember the syntax, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `NSPredicate` with `NSArray` like this

```
NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"foo" forKey:@"BAR"]];    
NSArray *filtered = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(BAR == %@)", @"foo"]];
```